# Can't generate pdf with Laravel-snappy in background

Tags: laravel, laravel-snappy, knp-snappy

I'm developing an application that works perfectly when the pdf is generated by a "normal process" (when a logged user click on generate button pdf).
My question is, I'm trying to send these pdf by email so I'm trying to generate it in a background job but the package throws this error:
The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /var/www/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: not found

I'm pretty sure that everything is installed and working fine because I can manually generate a pdf.

Thanks in advance,
André Luiz